# Sanitize HTML String without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML for length check

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I sanitize string without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React JSX. Requirement is to check the length of sanitized html string and then only include the component. Something like

```
    var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
       render:function(){
         return (
            {this.props.htmlString.length > 0 ? <Child htmlString={this.props.htmlString} : null}
         )
       }
    })

var Child = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return (
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.htmlString}}></p>
      )
    }
})
```

Everything works fine but fails when `this.props.htmlString='&nbsp'` . In this case length > 0 and component gets included. So I want to check the length of innerHTML before the element inclusion itself.

One Possible Solution I came across is something like :

```
var html = "&nbsp;";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html; //check the length of innerHTML now
```

But I am looking for a cleaner one more of react type.

Comment: I don't think there's a way with react but let's see what people say.. I'd be interested to know why you're doing this strange code too ;)

Comment: @DominicTobias For some reason I am getting editor html from rest API. Can't resolve that due to some backlogs

Comment: The solution you provided is correct - AFAIK there's no other browser API for resolving HTML into plaintext than filling a DOM element with it.

Answer (score 2):

As you already suggested, resolving a HTML string into plain text is easily done by filling a DOM element with it.

```
function htmlToText(htmlString) {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = htmlString;
  return el.textContent;
}
```

This turns your markup into plaintext:

```
htmlToText('&nbsp;') === '\xa0'  // non-breaking space character
```

Checking that the resolved text isn't empty is then trivial:

```
htmlToText('&nbsp;').trim().length === 0
htmlToText('&nbsp; FOO ').trim().length === 3
```

---

There's no "React way" to do this, because if you're setting HTML directly from string, it's only resolved when actually injected into the DOM. Of course you could use this tool to create a [HOC](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775):

```
const nonEmptyHtml = Component => props => {
  const html = props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML;
  if (html && !htmlToText(html).trim().length) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
const NonEmptyParagraph = nonEmptyHtml('p');
ReactDOM.render(<NonEmptyParagraph dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlString} />);
```